# js date picker not fully functional

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working on a project for work, and I apologize as this is only my second question to this site, but when I run my program in Visual Studio, everything works fine.  But once it's live on the production side, the JS Date Picker is not fully working.  By that I mean you can click on the date box and the date picker shows up, but only as the dates and next/previous plus the drop down box for which month you want.  However, this is all overlaid overtop of the website so the background or window background is not showing.  For the life of me, I cannot figure this out, and I can't even figure out how to pose it as a question to search for an answer.  A sample of the code would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui.css"> </link>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.ui.js"> </script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.ui.js"> </script>
```

The full directory would be:  `\\chprdapp02\Badge\Scripts`

This is the correct directory for the file, and I've tried typing in even the level above, and even the full directory for the live version but to no avail.  I just simply do not know what differentiates between the pre and post versions.  If I've screwed up the question somehow, let me know and I'll correct it immediately.  Thanks ahead of time for any and all help.

Comment: Why are you importing two versions of jQueryUI?

Comment: Can you please show your datepicker function code there?

Comment: And zero of jQuery? So what errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: so if version 1 failed, version 2 still works? :)

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cache? ctrl+f5?

Comment: I apologize guys, I'm pretty much new to corporate level programming (I'm more of a network guy working on his degrees in computer sciences).  What happened was the files were set to "do not copy" in Visual Studio so when they were put into production, the CSS for the datepickers, and the images we had to save to show the buttons, etc, were not copied over.  I figured this out after a day of frustration and 60 seconds after asking this question when I had to get up and step back from the project.  So once I replaced those files, everything worked.  Thanks again however :)